# Aumentar tamanho do input

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Alguém sabe como eu aumento o tamanho do input abaixo ?

```html
<td>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
    <input type="number" autocomplete="off" id="{{reg.id}}" value="{{reg.valorMultaJuros}}" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control text-input" (blur)="vMultaJuros($event)">
  </div>
</td>
```

[image: Input]

Comment: Acho que o <td> de sua tabela esta limitando seu input

Comment: Concordo com o @brunox99x como vc pode ver aqui http://prntscr.com/naoneg o problema é que o input não tem para onde crescer, pois a TD está limitando o tamanho dele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa, você pode inserir esse tamanho através do css, para que o `td` aumente.

```css
.text-input{
  width:300px
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
    <input type="number" autocomplete="off" id="{{reg.id}}" value="{{reg.valorMultaJuros}}" min="0" step="0.01" data-number-to-fixed="2" data-number-stepfactor="100" class="form-control text-input" (blur)="vMultaJuros($event)">
  </div>
</td>
```